# How to save file with current time in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, screenshot

I'm newbie with Python and Selenium and trying to get screenshots of specific page with time of screenshot displayed in filename, following is code snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from time import gmtime, strftime
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://google.com')
time.sleep(3)
browser.get_screenshot_as_file('C:\\path\\screenshots\\(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())).png')
browser.quit()
```

BTW, how can I set Chrome window size when running it?

And the main question: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect `(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()))` will do inside the string?

Comment: I expect the resulted file name to look like 2017-12-20 12:26:55.png

Comment: Okay, that evaluation is not done inside the string. Python makes no assumptions about the string contents.

Comment: @pavelryzhkov, was my answer helpful? If yes -- check a tick near my answer, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Python makes no assumptions about the contents of your string. If you want to insert a datetime, you'd need to first call `gmtime`, get the result, and then insert it into a string with `str.format`.

Here's a simple example  -

```
>>> "C:\\path\\screenshots\\{}.png".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
'C:\\path\\screenshots\\2017-12-20 12:37:29.png'
```

What you've been doing thus far is inserting the expression as a substring. Like I mentioned, python does not make any assumptions about your string, and does not evaluate its contents in any way.

Comment: @DebanjanB Thank you! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

to set the window size - driver.set_window_size(800,800)
or you can use options method of chrome webdriver-

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
  executable_path='C:/Users/user/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe', 
  options=options)
```

and run it.

Answer (score -1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from time import gmtime, strftime
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
filename = (strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S", gmtime()))
browser.get_screenshot_as_file("C:\\parh\\screenshots\\" + filename + ".png")
browser.quit()
print (strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
print (filename)
```

Comment: See my edit, I'd recommend `str.format` instead of string concatenation, it's cleaner.